# Resizing in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am brand new to iOS development, and I am trying to implement a rotatable and resizable user interface. The problem that I am encountering is re-setting the position of UI elements upon rotation. I can't even get the simple code below to work properly:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return YES; 
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation               
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
  if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
      toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {        
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(502.0, 207.0, 73.0, 44.0);
  } else {  
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(197.0, 69.0, 73.0, 44.0);
  }
}
```

I have de-selected the Autoresize Subviews option; however, the button still ends up in the same spot. I have logged the frame position, which appears to have the correct coordinates, but it is definitely not ending up that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first panel of Utility inspect. uncheck the use auto-layout.

[image]